# How do I dynamically get the value of a property of a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I might not know what to call this, but essentially I want to pass the name of the property dynamically and then get the value of that property within my objects data property. Something like this:

```
function myFunc(e, myProperty) {

    alert( e.data[myProperty] );
}

var myValue = myFunc(myObject, "someField");
```

I get the value *undefined*.

I think the equivalent in ColdFusion would be something[myPropertyName] and I'm wondering if there is something similar in JavaScript.

UPDATE: Apparently getting the value works, but not where I'm trying to pass the dynamic property as a name/value pair to an AJAX request.

```
var myValue = e.data[myProperty];

var myData = { myProperty: myValue }
```

In the code above *myProperty* is being passed as *"myProperty"*

Comment: Your syntax is correct; that is the way to dynamically access an object property by name in Javascript. Can you post the data you're working with? That is most likely where your problem lies.

Comment: Uh, it kinda looks right to me already. It is case sensitive of course

Comment: shouldn't it be just `e[myProperty]`

Comment: if you did `alert(e.data.someField);` would you get anything?

Comment: Er... I was assuming that your object contains a property called `data` which contains a property called `someField`. If you're just trying to access `e.somefield`, you would use `e[somefield]`, not `e.data[someField]`.

Comment: can you show your objects structure?

Comment: what type of object do you have here? is it html element ?

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the result only after the Ajax call has completed? That is, are you treating your code as synchronous when it is really asynchronous? If you're not sure, please show a simplified version of your code including the Ajax fetch.

Comment: e.somefield to get the data in your case, and if it didn't work. I think for better help just post you code as it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
var myValue = e.data[myProperty];

var myData = { };
myData[myProperty] = myValue;
```

That should allow you to dynamically create an object with property named `myProperty`

Answer (score 0):

worked for me:

```
function myFunc(e, myProperty) {
    alert( e.data[myProperty] );
}

myObject = { data: {} };
myObject.data['someField'] = 123;
var myValue = myFunc(myObject, "someField");
```